# by mutableStateOf seem to fail in this situation

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a funny one

```kotlin
class RoleState(
    var roles: List<String> = emptyList(),
    var selectedRoles: List<String> = emptyList()
)
```

in my ViewModel I have

```kotlin
var rolesState by mutableStateOf(RoleState())
```

[image] Below

```kotlin
rolesState = rolesState.copy(
    selectedRoles = result.data ?: kotlin.run {
        _eventFlow.emit(value =UiEvent.ShowSnackbar(uiText = UiText.errorUnknown()))
        return@launch
    }
)
```

Normally `.copy` would work, but now emits Unresolved reference: copy

Only reason I can think of is that the State class needs to be primatives and Data Classes only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RoleState` has to be a data class in order to get the compiler to create a `copy` function. If you don't want to make it a data class you have to provide/implement the copy function on yourself.

See the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) on data classes for more information.

Comment: lol I knew that - how stupid of me not to see that! Thanks man